# How to convert object to array?

Tags: php, joomla

I need to create custom array of Joomla database config, so i am doing it like:

```
$config =& JFactory::getConfig();
$db['default']['hostname'] = $config->getValue('config.host');
```

But getting an error: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type JDatabaseMySQLi as array in /Sites/joomla/administrator/components/com_***** on line 217`.

I also tried like this:

```
die(var_dump($config->getValue('config.host')));
//string(9) "localhost"

$temp_var = $config->getValue('config.host');
die(var_dump($temp_var));
//string(9) "localhost"
```

Comment: try using (string) $config->getValue('config.host');

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary tried already - no luck.

Comment: can you print_r($config->getValue('config.host'));

Comment: As this is returning string I think problem lies somewhere else

Comment: Where you defined $db, Please show me the code where you declare that. I think that $db is an object of mysqli connection

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary $db is just an array

Comment: Ok can you show us the code from start so that we can debug the problem easily

Comment: @user1692333 Please show `var_dump($db);`

Answer (score 0):

In Joomla 3.0

You can get each value  like this:

```
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$db['default']['hostname'] = $config->get('host');
// Show them
var_dump($config);
var_dump($config->get('host'));
var_dump($db);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the $db part, not the $config.
You're trying to threat the $db object (probably created by `JFactory::getDbo()`) as an array.

If that's an own variable you want to use for something, try renaming it to something else to avoid a conflict with the apparently already existing $db object.

Or use the JDatabase class like described here: http://docs.joomla.org/Accessing_the_database_using_JDatabase

Answer (score 0):

Your error message is very clear - you are trying to use and object called `$db` of class `JDatabaseMySQLi` as an array. If you created `$db` as follows:

```php
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
// N.B. $db is already setup for the Joomla! database.
```

The you have database connector `object` (using the MySQLi adpater) for the Joomla! installations local database (i.e. the one setup in your `configuration.php`). This not an `array` — but your line of code is trying to use it as an `array`

```php
$db['default']['hostname'] = $config->getValue('config.host');
```

***Note:** this line above is wrong*

If you want to setup a connection to a database using credential other than those stored in your `configuration.php` (say a remote database) you can use the following approach:

```php
$options = array(
    'host'      => 'remote_host',
    'user'      => 'remote_user',
    'password'  => 'remote_password',
    'database'  => 'remote_name',
    'prefix'    => 'remote_table_prefix',
);

$rDBC = JDatabase::getInstance($options);
```